# Need help to understand Overlay Network formed by Flannel

Tags: kubernetes

I am very new to flannel overlay network with kubernetes, we want to know how packets are transmitted across container in different host using flannel overlay network, below mentioned reference link which contains diagram in order to transmit packet between container in different host, can any one explain how its happen? Reference link ::  https://github.com/coreos/flannel

Answer (score 1):

NB: I didn't write flannel, so I'm not the perfect person to answer...

As far as I understand it, by default flannel uses UDP packet encapsulation to deliver packets between nodes in the network.

So if a compute node at 1.2.3.4 is hosting a subnet with a CIDR like 10.244.1.0/24, then all packets for that CIDR are encapsulated in UDP and sent to 1.2.3.4 where the are decapsulated and placed onto the bridge for the subnet.

Hope that helps!
--brendan